# How to store Jenkins project build numbers, build date and build time into file?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-cli

I want to store projects build numbers, build date and build time into file after triggering the job.
I tried for this ans but it is storing the latest build number into file and deleting the previous one.

> Windows Platform - Execute windows batch command
>
> echo jenkins-build=%BUILD_NUMBER% > Drive:\path\to\file.properties

Comment: Posting just a comment since I'm not sure this is a full answer. `>` creates a new file and writes to it; use `>>` to append to an existing file (creates the file if it doesn't exist)

Comment: >> Yes it's working.

Comment: FYI, posted my comment as an actual answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the output redirection using `>`. A single `>` creates a new file and writes to it.

To append to an existing file, you should use `>>` (it will still create the file if it doesn't exist).

**Reference:** https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: More specific ans for this question is : 

echo jenkins-build & Time =%BUILD_NUMBER%, %BUILD_TIMESTAMP% >> Drive:\path\to\file.properties